# What's the lowest natural integer in which they can be divided by two factor pairs... [Resolved, don't answer]

Tags: number-theory, factoring

Today morning, I found some numbers which have 2 factor pairs accepting the condition that the largest of them divided by the other must be lower than the 2. For example, I found $720$ which satisfies the condition since their two factor pairs $30, 24$ and $36, 20$ and 36/20, 30/24 are smaller than two. Can you find smallest natural that does so? I found 180 at least. P.S. don't include square numbers.

Comment: Seems simple program will do this, as you do not need any mathematical investigation.

Comment: dividing gives the quotient , not the difference. $120=8\cdot 15=10\cdot 12$ is a smaller example, I have not checked yet whether it is the smallest.

Comment: why not to take $60$?

Comment: You are looking for a number $n$ with two factors $x$ where $\sqrt{n} < x < \sqrt{2n}$.  I think $n=120$ is the smallest with $10.95 < x <15.49$ so $12$ and $15$.  With $60$ you have $7.75 < x <10.95$ but neither $8$ nor $9$ are factors of $60$

Comment: @zkutch  $12/5>2$

Comment: Oh no, I made a mistake! I just fixed that.

Comment: @zkutch 60 has 1,60 and 2,30 and 4,15 and 10,6 and 12,5 and 1 follows the conditions

Comment: It's hard when conditions changing: can it formally written as we want 2 pairs s.t. for $a,b$ factors, $\frac{\max (a,b)}{\min (a,b)}<2$?

Comment: If equality is allowed, we have $72=8\cdot 9=6\cdot 12$ as the smallest example, otherwise it is $120$

Comment: @zkutch you got the point! That's what I meant.

Comment: @Peter I meant < not $\leq$

Comment: The first $10$ solutions are $$[120, 180, 240, 252, 336, 360, 378, 420, 432, 480]$$  hence $180$ is actually the second-smallest.

Comment: @Peter. Python list?

Comment: @zkutch pari/gp . Code is : a=[];for(n=1,1000,v=select(m->(n/m^2<2)*(m^2<n),divisors(n));if(length(v)==2,a=concat(a,n)))

Comment: @Peter Thank you!

Comment: I should have used "length(v)>=2", fortunately, the smallest example saitisfying >2 is $840$, so the first $10$ solutions remain.

Comment: @Peter. Fine. If you post it as answer, then +1 from me. That's what the snake does to mathematicians. I just didn't understand what it is "pari/gp"?

Comment: @zkutch OK, I will use the corrected version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the PARI/GP code and the table (the second column means the number of possible pairs) :

```
gp > for(n=1,1000,v=select(m->(n/m^2<2)*(m^2<n),divisors(n));if(length(v)>=2,print(n,"   ",length(v))))
120   2
180   2
240   2
252   2
336   2
360   2
378   2
420   2
432   2
480   2
504   2
540   2
594   2
600   2
630   2
660   2
672   2
700   2
720   2
756   2
780   2
792   2
840   3
858   2
864   2
924   2
936   2
960   2
gp >
```

We can easily adjust this for more pairs , for example :

```
gp > for(n=1,5000,v=select(m->(n/m^2<2)*(m^2<n),divisors(n));if(length(v)>=3,print(n,"   ",length(v))))
840   3
1080   3
1260   3
1440   3
1680   3
1980   3
2016   3
2160   3
2340   3
2520   4
2640   3
2880   3
3024   3
3080   3
3120   3
3150   3
3300   3
3360   3
3600   3
3696   3
3780   3
3900   3
3960   3
4032   3
4080   3
4200   3
4320   3
4368   3
4536   3
4560   3
4620   3
4680   3
4800   3
4950   3
gp >
```

It is interesting to find the smallest solution for $2,3,4,\cdots$ pairs

Comment: Very good, thanks!

Comment: Thank you, but I forgot a little thing, ruling out the squares. This can easily be achieved by a slight modification. The first number to be ruled out is $3600$.